# Adding side notes to each property in MongoDB document

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection with a collection of documents. Each document has around 20 different properties with different data types (e.g. Int, Double, String).

I am searching for an efficient way or the appropriate way to add side notes to each property.

My thought (I am using C# to model the document structure) is for each property, instead of 
:

```
public int PageRank {get; set; }
```

to use:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> PageRank {get; set;}
```

This means that each item in the document is a collection of both the value and the string for the side note.

**The side notes will be seen at the front-end by the user.**

Any better implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idan, for performance reasons, you should consider your use case from the MongoDB point of view -- not from the object oriented language point of view.  The way it ends up looking in C# is an afterthought -- its the DB performance that counts.  So, when querying your documents, if the side notes are mostly not needed, it will be better to place them into a separate collection (possibly) thus reducing the size of each document and enabling MongoDB to read more of them into the available memory.  If the user does need to look at the side notes, you would do this with a separate query.  You know your usage scenario better, so its up to you to decide how to do this, but its these kinds of design decisions that you need to concern yourself with -- and the C# code will be shaped according to your schema

Comment: @alemerdev, Thansk. The side notes will be seen by the user. My issue is how to keep track of which side note belong to which attribute (can be in various levels) when I use them in separate document (each document for each most parent Id of the main document)

Comment: What about changing each "flat" attribute to a compound "subdocument" pair consisting of attribute value and a side note?  Or, you can represent each attribute value as an array where the first index of the array is the original value and the second index is the side note?

Comment: That's exactly what I was demonstrating in the example in my question, and I was wondering if this has an impact of some kind and whether it's the best way to do it.